# About write restrictions to google fit

Tags: google-fit

I used to be able to write to the following information on Google Fit, but now it seems that it is not possible.

> DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT

Also, the following information was previously reflected immediately after writing, but now it takes several hours to reflect,

> DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM

I'd like to know accurate information about when the above specifications were met, but I couldn't get to that information.
If anyone knows, please let me know.